# Graduate Certificate After Masters

Tags: graduate-admissions, canada

I have a Masters Degree from the UK and I would like to apply for a graduate Certificate studies in a field completely different from my Masters degree in Canada.

Would there be an issue in processing the study permit to Canada?

Comment: Is this a question about immigration? Or visas?

Comment: Note to readers that a Graduate Certificate program is a non-degree professional skills advancement program offered in many places and in many fields (web search). It normally requires a few courses beyond the bachelors degree.

Comment: And a Canadian Study Permit is a limited term residence permit for study in Canada.